# How can i take a screenshot of the webbrowser hidden and minimized

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, screenshot, bitblt

I am trying to make a application the takes screnshots of the webbrowser hidden and minimized and put it to a picturebox or save it as a bitmap. I know that there are drawtobitmap, bitblt, copyfromscreen and some other ways, but no one do the job if the control or the form is minimized or hiddenm background. These functions only work if the form is active and foreground. I tried many and many codes based on many kind of tricks to do this, but no one worked.
How can I proceed?

Comment: [**Capturing Minimized Window: A Kid's Trick - CodeProject**](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20651/Capturing-Minimized-Window-A-Kid-s-Trick)

Comment: Hello. Itis working correctly on webbrowser common sites, but not on a flash game content. In these cases, it gives me a black scree. I have searched and i found that the microsoft had added a "Window Content Protection". How can i go against it?

Comment: Games, flash apps and alike you usually cannot take screenshots of with the regular methods. Look into taking screenshots with DirectX or something similar for that.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote my last comment in a kind of rush so I didn't focus on the _"Content Protection"_ part. If you really are dealing with something that uses content protection, then I think you're out of luck. Trying to go around the encryption or the protected display is most likely too hard to be found simply in an internet article.

Comment: I have downloaded a SlimDX dll. But i don't know yet how to search the surface of my webbrowser flash content and how to capture the screen. How do i proceed?

Comment: This is too broad for Stack Overflow and also for me to continue. Besides that I also don't know. Google how you can take screenshots with DirectX/SlimDX/SharpDX, but be aware that you're not going to find a simple solution because DirectX _is complicated_.